# Secure websocket (wss) client in java

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, mutual-authentication

I am trying to connect to a secure websocket server, i am using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.8.RC0</version>
        </dependency>
```

as a library, we have mutual auth for the server and client i have keystore with what is wrong here or a any other implementation for secure websocket client.
here is my code,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;


import org.eclipse.jetty.*;

public class WebSocketClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException{

        new WebSocketClientTest().run(new URI("wss:/websocket:443/secure/12234"));

    }


    public void run(URI destinationUri) throws IOException
    {
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        Resource keyStoreResorce = Resource.newResource(this.getClass().getResource("certstore.jks"));
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(keyStoreResorce);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("changeit!");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("");
        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();

        MyWebSocket socket = new MyWebSocket();
        try{
            client.start();
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            System.out.println("Connecting to : "+ destinationUri);
            client.connect(socket, destinationUri, request);
            System.out.println("line x1");
            socket.awaitClose(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("line x2");

        }catch (Throwable t){
            System.out.println(t.getStackTrace());

        }finally{
            try{
                client.stop();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @WebSocket
    public class MyWebSocket {
        private final CountDownLatch closeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        @OnWebSocketConnect
        public void onConnect(Session session){

            System.out.println("WebSocket Opened in client side");
            try{
                System.out.println("Sending message : Ready");
                session.getRemote().sendString("Ready");
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @OnWebSocketMessage
        public void onMessage(String message){
            System.out.println("Message from server : "+message);
        }

        @OnWebSocketClose
        public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason){
            System.out.println("WebSocket Closed. code:"+ statusCode);
        }

        public boolean awaitClose(int duration, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException{
            return this.closeLatch.await(duration, unit);
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: any solution for this ?